# Problem with Deleting element ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I tried to use Dependency Injection in my ASP.Net Core MVC Project.

After many approaches I'm struggling with complete the Delete Action.

Manage Action from Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Manage()
        {
            var categories = _categoryService.GetAll()
                .Select(c => new CategoryListingModel
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Title,
                    Description = c.Description
                });

            return View(categories);
        }
```

Delete Action from Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var cat = _categoryService.GetById(id);

            if(cat == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Category with ID: {id} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }
            else
            {
                _categoryService.Delete(id);

                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }
        }
```

Delete Method from Service:

```cs
public async Task Delete(int id)
        {
            var category = GetById(id);
            _context.Remove(category);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

After Deleting confirmation list of categories just refresh without any changes.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to await the `_categoryService.Delete(id)` call, and the **Manage** page gets rendered before the category is removed from the repository.

Try this:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var cat = _categoryService.GetById(id);
    
        if(cat == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Category with ID: {id} cannot be found";
            return View("NotFound");
        }
        else
        {
            await _categoryService.Delete(id);
    
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }
    }
```

Also, consider adding an `Async` suffix to the `categoryService.Delete` method name to make it easier for other developers to see that the method should be awaited.